# Determining the drivers to be installed on the desktop

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I recently reinstalled win7(64) on my *Dell desktop. But unfortunately I did not take a backup of my drivers setting/executive files.

I cannot even access the Internet since even the ethernet driver is not installed. How do I determine which drivers should I install? How do I even know the model of my desktop?

When I type `wmic csproduct get name` it only gives me `GA-A75-D3H`. I do not know how to use this information to get drivers?

At least if I can make my internet work (by downloading the right drivers on my laptop), I can let the required list of drivers to be identified (on my desktop) through an online connection. I can do the rest then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Dell computers, the way that I usually get drivers is from Dell's website, http://support.dell.com/.

First you need to find the service tag number, which should be printed on the case somewhere.  [Here's a link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/43268030@N04/4519076706/) to what a service tag sticker looks like.  For recent computers, it's 7 letters and numbers, for example, `95HAG1J`.

If you can't find the service tag sticker, you should be able to see it in the BIOS, or you can try running the [Dell Asset Tag Utility](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/usgen1/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=R80775&c=us&l=en&cs=&s=gen), which should give it to you.

Then you can go to the above Dell support link.  Putting the service tag into their website will give you a full list of the hardware that the computer shipped with and links to the necessary drivers.  You can then download the network card driver and use a USB key or similar mechanism to transfer it to the desktop.  The current home and office driver download [link is here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriversHome/NeedProductSelection), but you may want to navigate in from the top to see the various other areas of the support site, and in case the deep link changes in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot read the tag sticker on the top of the desktop (CPU). Is there any other (cmd etc) way to get it?

Comment: Just updated answer

Comment: Do not know why the downloaded driver was not compatible (trying other options as per your answer)

Comment: No, I haven't had a problem unless someone put 3rd party hardware into the computer.  Sometimes there are a few different downloads, but Dell will in general tell you what the computer shipped with, the day it shipped, and what drivers to install.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the device manager to get the hardware ids
Then use another computer to download the drivers

Right click on my computer and click properties and then on the left side there should be device manager
Next you will see things that are not installed in yellow 
You willright click them and then go to properties.
In the drop down box you will select hardware id and then follow my steps on top.

Comment: Thanks @tko123 How do you get the device name (which option to choose?)?

Comment: Copy the first row of hardware id only

Comment: Sorry...I will appreciate if you can tell me how to locate/search for the driver once I have the hardware id (`PCI\VEN_...`). I have been trying but without any success.

Comment: Combined help of tko123 (+1) and @dsolimano resolved the issue